# Why would a bathroom emit an odor if pipes aren't clogged?

Tags: bathroom, sewer, odors

House has crawl space and the pipes aren't clogged, yet bathroom has stench that wasn't there yesterday. Only thing different today than yesterday is that it's raining today. Why would stench all of a sudden appear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you are smelling sewer gases. Two common ways those will come up drain lines are from a dry trap (make sure water has run in each drain within the past several months) or a failing wax seal under the toilet (you may notice water damage under the toilet when this happens, but not always). The other issue could be a blocked vent line which would result in gurgling in a drain when you use the plumbing elsewhere.

Comment: One of our bathrooms at work has a shower which probably gets used once every other year. And needs a bucket of water every three months to replenish the trap, otherwise sewer gas has free entry into the adjacent lunchroom.